# Laravel's whereBetween method not working with two timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, php-carbon

I'm attempting to retrieve data from the database that falls between `$booking_start_formatted` and `$booking_end` based on the `session_start` column. However, it only selects data earlier than `$booking_start_formatted`.

```php
public function store(Request $request, Utils $utils)
{
    $request->validate([
        "user_id" => "required|int",
        "booking_start" => "required",
    ]);

    try {
        $booking_start = Carbon::parse($request->get("booking_start"));
        $booking_start_formatted =  $booking_start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $booking_end =  $booking_start->addMinute(45)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $booking = Bookings::query()->whereBetween("session_start", [$booking_start_formatted, $booking_end])->get();
        return $utils->message("error", $booking, 400);
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // Handle the exception
        return $utils->message("error", $e->getMessage(), 400);
    }
}
```

The timestamp format I'm using is '2024-03-31 06:35:13'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the `Carbon` object or change to immutable object. Carbon is a mutable object by default.

Use `copy` or `clone` method :

```
$booking_end =  $booking_start->copy()->addMinute(45)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$booking_end =  $booking_start->clone()->addMinute(45)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Use `object cloning` method : [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

```
$booking_end =  (clone $booking_start)->addMinute(45)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

---

Look this Stack Overflow post, same issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905830/11836673